# Reverting DB to the initial state before the first migration in .NET Core 2+?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to roll back my database to the total pre-state, i.e. invoke every `Down()` method in all the migrations, including the initial one.

Checking [this blog](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations), there's no hints on that, despite it being rather comprehensive. There's been a way as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index#migrate-to-a-specific-version-including-downgrade) (in short: [Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205178/1525840)) but it doesn't work in Core, regrettably.

My workaround at the moment is to go `drop database` but I feel it'd be letting the computer win and I want to show it who's the boss. (It's me.)

Other than that, it seems that google fails me this time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at EF6 documentation. EF Core documentation for PMC is [Update-Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#update-database) with optional parameter `-Migration <String>` with the following semantics

> The target migration. Migrations may be identified by name or by ID. The number 0 is a special case that means before the first migration and causes all migrations to be reverted. If no migration is specified, the command defaults to the last migration.

and example

> The following example reverts all migrations.
>
> `Update-Database -Migration 0`

Shortly, passing the special value `0` does what you are asking for.

.NET Core CLI command is [dotnet ef database update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update)
 with optional parameter for migration name with the same semantics, e.g.

```
dotnet ef database update 0
```

Comment: Cool. And makes sense in a way. Are all the migrations numbered so that `Update-Database -Migration 7` would work too (for the 7th iteration, should it exist)?

Comment: Negative. For other migrations you should use the name as shown in the examples. `0` is the only special "name", represented by [Migration.InitialDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migration.initialdatabase?view=efcore-2.1) constant.